# How to display all user input numbers in C?

Tags: c, user-input

I am required to create a function that uses arrays and a menu system that displays:

the sum of all numbers entered, the average of numbers entered, and all numbers entered. It will allow the user to enter up to 1000 numbers.

I have the majority of the code working, I just need to figure out how to display all of the numbers a user has entered so far. Would anyone be able to help me with this? Thanks!

I've tried displaying the number entered, but this does not fit the assignment requirements.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
/*

Title: Array Intro
Author: James Henderson
Desc: a program designed to display the sume, average, and all previous numbers entered of user input numbers
Date: 11/06/19
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//Create Variables
//used for math
int counter = 0;
float number, sum = 0.0, average;
//user input number
int userInt;
int userInput[1000];

//Void Function

static void sumFunction(userInput)
{
    printf("\n\tWelcome!\n");
    printf("Enter 1 to begin:\n");
    scanf("%i", &userInput);

    //switch statement
    while (1)
    {
        switch (userInput)
        {
        case 1:

            printf("\nEnter a number:\n");
            while (1)
            {
                scanf("%i", &userInput);
                //determine sum
                number = userInput;
                sum += number;
                counter++;

                average = sum / counter;

                printf("\n The average of the numbers is %.2f", average);
                printf("\n The sum of the numbers is %.2lf", sum);
                printf("\n You may enter up to 1000 numbers");
                printf("\n You have entered %d numbers\n", counter);
                if (counter == 1000)
                {
                    printf("\nThank you for using my program! Have a lovely day :)");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `userInput` as if it were a single `int`, but it is an array. You should be reading numbers into `userInput[counter]`. You have one `while(1)` layer too many inside you function, and an extra one in `main`. If the first number given is not `1`, you have an infinite loop due to the `switch`. You should just get rid of the initial `Enter 1 to begin`. There is no reason to pass `userInput` to the function (it is global), and you are missing its type in the function parameter declaration (i.e. `void sumFunction(userInput)` vs. `void sumFunction(int* userInput)`.

Comment: You are not checking for errors from `scanf`. I know this looks like a big list, but it is good to learn these things early, and most of this should be easy to fix. Just make sure you understand *why* the change should be made.

Comment: Why are you using global variables? Why are you using static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was right, just look how i used **userInput**. Below code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//Create Variables
//used for math
int counter = 0;
float number, sum = 0.0, average;
//user input number
int userInt;
int userInput[1000];

//Void Function

static void sumFunction()
{
    printf("\n\tWelcome!\n");
    printf("Enter 1 to begin:\n");
    scanf("%i", &userInt);

    //switch statement
    while (1)
    {
        switch (userInt)
        {
        case 1:

            printf("\nEnter a number:\n");
            while (1)
            {
                scanf("%i", &userInput[counter]);
                //determine sum
                number = userInput[counter];
                sum += number;
                counter++;

                average = sum / counter;

                printf("\n The average of the numbers is %.2f", average);
                printf("\n The sum of the numbers is %.2lf", sum);
                printf("\n You may enter up to 1000 numbers");
                printf("\n You have entered %d numbers\n", counter);

                // number entered so far
                printf("\n The list of numbers entered so far : \n");
                for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
                    printf("  %d ",userInput[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                if (counter == 1000)
                {
                    printf("\nThank you for using my program! Have a lovely day :)");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    sumFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Very helpful :)